# Ajax não recebe resposta de controller laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3

**PHP**

```
public function salvar_distrito(Request $request)
{
    $distritos=Distrito::create($request->all());
    if ($distritos) {
        $messagem = 'Adicionado com Sucesso!';
        echo true;
    }
    // Se houver algum erro ao inserir
    else {
        echo "Não foi possível inserir a mensagem no momento.";
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        // Executa assim que o botão de salvar for clicado
        $('#guardar').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // Pega os valores dos inputs e coloca nas variáveis
            var nome = $('#nome').val();
            var provincia_id = $('#provincia_id').val();

            // Método post do Jquery
            $.post('salvar.distrito', {
                nome:nome,
                provincia_id:provincia_id,

            }, function(data){
                // Valida a resposta

                if(data == 1){
                    // Limpa os inputs
                    $('input, textarea').val('');
                    alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso.');
                }else {
                    alert(resposta);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No `Laravel` para você poder enviar algo via `post` você precisa colocar no formulário o `@csrf`, e ao enviar utilizando o ajax você precisa especificar ele no `headers`, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    async: true,
    data: { nome : nome, provincia_id: provincia_id },
    success: function (data) {
        //Dados que chegaram do seu servidor
    }
});
```

Obs: esta `url` é a sua rota, mas não separada por pontos como no Laravel, mas a `url` como é mostrada no navegador.

Um exemplo utilizando o seu código, verifique se a rota esta correta.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        // Executa assim que o botão de salvar for clicado
        $('#guardar').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // Pega os valores dos inputs e coloca nas variáveis
            var nome = $('#nome').val();
            var provincia_id = $('#provincia_id').val();

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'post',
                url: 'salvar/distrito/',//Acredito que esta seja a sua rota, ela deve ser a mesma que aparece no navegador
                async: true,
                data: { nome : nome, provincia_id: provincia_id },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Valida a resposta
                    if(data == 1){
                        // Limpa os inputs
                        $('input, textarea').val('');
                        alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso.');
                    }else {
                        alert(resposta);
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Fiz teste, porém o resultado foi o mesmo. A resposta não recebo em Json.

Comment: você testou a sua url fora do ajax?

Comment: Sim testei e grava os dados sem problemas. Mesmo com o ajax, os dados sao gravados no banco, mas nao me da alerta via json.

Comment: Mas de onde vem a variável 'resposta', porque neste código ela não tem referencia em nenhum lugar.

Comment: Deveria ser 'data'.

Comment: depende, data é o json que o seu código php retornou, então em dada esta tudo que o php trouxe para você.

Comment: Se você retornou do seu php por exemplo 'dados salvos', se você colocar alert(data), vai ser mostrado no alert 'dados salvos'.